# Django login() does not work if you access the page not directly, but through a redirect from another site

Tags: python, django, redirect, oauth, twitch

If you go to the callback page directly in the browser, the authorization works and will be saved, but if you get to the callback through a redirect from another site (in my case Twitch), the authorization will not be saved, how can I fix it?

```py
class CallbackView(django.views.generic.RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some checks
        # ....

        user = django.contrib.auth.authenticate(
            self.request,
            token=self.request.GET.get('code'),
        )

        if user and user.is_active:
            # this code is triggered
            print(self.request.user.is_authenticated) # False
            django.contrib.auth.login(
                self.request,
                user,
                backend='twitch_auth.backends.TwitchOAuth2Backend',
            )
            print(self.request.user.is_authenticated) # True
            return django.urls.reverse('twitch_auth:profile')

        django.contrib.messages.error(self.request, 'Error')
        return django.urls.reverse('homepage:home')
```

```py
class ProfileView(django.views.generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'twitch_auth/profile.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.user.is_authenticated) # True if open callback directly in the browser. False if it is redirect from Twitch
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In addition, the sessionid on the profile page is empty if Twitch redirects to the callback and not empty if the callback is called directly